# Eigen efficiency of Matrix-Matrix multiplication vs several Matrix-Vector multiplication

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

Assuming the following relations

```
a = M u
b = M v
c = M w
```

Where `a, b` and `c` are three `[6x1]` vectors, `M` is a `[6x15]` matrix and `u, v` and `w` are three `[15x1]` .

These operations are done for a set of several different `M` matrices. I thus have a stack of `M` matrices, namely `M_stack` with dimensions ranging from `[2000x15]` to `[3000x15]` depending on the length of the stack. Multiplying `u, v` and `w`  by `M_stack` gives `a_stack, b_stack` and `c_stack` with dimensions ranging from `[2000x1]` to `[3000x1]`.

```
a_stack = M_stack u
b_stack = M_stack v
c_stack = M_stack w
```

Now I was thinking that I could speed up this operation stacking `u, v` and `w` in a matrix `Z = [u v w]` with dimensions `[15x3]` and having `D = [a_stack b_stack c_stack]` with dimensions ranging from `[2000x3]` to `[3000x3]`

```
D = M_stack Z
```

I thought that this would have been faster as Eigen should optimize and parallelize Matrix-Matrix multiplication. However, I found that the version where I compute `a_stack, b_stack` and `c_stack` individually is faster.

Here's an example code using google benchmark.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>


struct Stack {

    void update()
    {
        D = M_stack*Z;
    }

    void updateInSeries()
    {
        a_stack = M_stack*u;
        b_stack = M_stack*v;
        c_stack = M_stack*w;
    }

    void updateNoAlias()
    {
        D.noalias() = M_stack*Z;
    }

    void updateInSeriesNoAlias()
    {
        a_stack.noalias() = M_stack*u;
        b_stack.noalias() = M_stack*v;
        c_stack.noalias() = M_stack*w;
    }




    unsigned int rows { 2300 };


    Eigen::MatrixXd M_stack { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 15) };


    Eigen::MatrixXd Z { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 3) };

    Eigen::MatrixXd D { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 3) };


    Eigen::MatrixXd u { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };
    Eigen::MatrixXd v { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };
    Eigen::MatrixXd w { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };

    Eigen::MatrixXd a_stack { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };
    Eigen::MatrixXd b_stack { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };
    Eigen::MatrixXd c_stack { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };




    void updateSized()
    {
        D_sized = M_stack_sized*Z_sized;
    }

    void updateInSeriesSized()
    {
        a_stack_sized = M_stack_sized*u_sized;
        b_stack_sized = M_stack_sized*v_sized;
        c_stack_sized = M_stack_sized*w_sized;
    }

    void updateNoAliasSized()
    {
        D_sized.noalias() = M_stack_sized*Z_sized;
    }

    void updateInSeriesNoAliasSized()
    {
        a_stack_sized.noalias() = M_stack_sized*u_sized;
        b_stack_sized.noalias() = M_stack_sized*v_sized;
        c_stack_sized.noalias() = M_stack_sized*w_sized;
    }



    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 15> M_stack_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 15) };


    Eigen::Matrix<double, 15, 3> Z_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 3) };

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> D_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 3) };


    Eigen::Matrix<double, 15, 1> u_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 15, 1> v_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 15, 1> w_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(15, 1) };

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> a_stack_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> b_stack_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> c_stack_sized { Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(rows, 1) };

};




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    const unsigned int repetitions = 5;


    ::benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("update", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.update();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateInSeries", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateInSeries();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateNoAlias", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateNoAlias();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateInSeriesNoAlias", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateInSeriesNoAlias();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);










    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateSized", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateSized();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateInSeriesSized", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateInSeriesSized();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateNoAliasSized", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateNoAliasSized();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("updateInSeriesNoAliasSized", [](::benchmark::State &t_state){
       Stack stack;

       while(t_state.KeepRunning())
           stack.updateInSeriesNoAliasSized();

    })->Repetitions(repetitions)->Unit(::benchmark::kMicrosecond);


    ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();


    return 0;
}
```

Running this example gives the following output in my machine.

```
Run on (16 X 4800 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 1280 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 24576 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 1.11, 0.48, 0.19
***WARNING*** CPU scaling is enabled, the benchmark real time measurements may be noisy and will incur extra overhead.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                            Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
update/repeats:5                                  25.4 us         25.4 us        28082
update/repeats:5                                  25.3 us         25.3 us        28082
update/repeats:5                                  25.1 us         25.1 us        28082
update/repeats:5                                  25.3 us         25.3 us        28082
update/repeats:5                                  25.3 us         25.3 us        28082
update/repeats:5_mean                             25.3 us         25.3 us            5
update/repeats:5_median                           25.3 us         25.3 us            5
update/repeats:5_stddev                          0.117 us        0.117 us            5
update/repeats:5_cv                               0.46 %          0.46 %             5
updateInSeries/repeats:5                          15.2 us         15.2 us        46088
updateInSeries/repeats:5                          15.2 us         15.2 us        46088
updateInSeries/repeats:5                          15.2 us         15.2 us        46088
updateInSeries/repeats:5                          15.2 us         15.2 us        46088
updateInSeries/repeats:5                          15.1 us         15.1 us        46088
updateInSeries/repeats:5_mean                     15.2 us         15.2 us            5
updateInSeries/repeats:5_median                   15.2 us         15.2 us            5
updateInSeries/repeats:5_stddev                  0.058 us        0.057 us            5
updateInSeries/repeats:5_cv                       0.38 %          0.38 %             5
updateNoAlias/repeats:5                           23.6 us         23.6 us        29484
updateNoAlias/repeats:5                           23.7 us         23.7 us        29484
updateNoAlias/repeats:5                           23.6 us         23.6 us        29484
updateNoAlias/repeats:5                           23.5 us         23.5 us        29484
updateNoAlias/repeats:5                           24.0 us         24.0 us        29484
updateNoAlias/repeats:5_mean                      23.7 us         23.7 us            5
updateNoAlias/repeats:5_median                    23.6 us         23.6 us            5
updateNoAlias/repeats:5_stddev                   0.203 us        0.203 us            5
updateNoAlias/repeats:5_cv                        0.86 %          0.86 %             5
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5                   14.0 us         14.0 us        50044
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5                   14.0 us         14.0 us        50044
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5                   14.0 us         14.0 us        50044
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5                   14.0 us         14.0 us        50044
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5                   14.0 us         14.0 us        50044
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5_mean              14.0 us         14.0 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5_median            14.0 us         14.0 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5_stddev           0.020 us        0.021 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAlias/repeats:5_cv                0.15 %          0.15 %             5
updateSized/repeats:5                             24.6 us         24.6 us        28335
updateSized/repeats:5                             24.5 us         24.5 us        28335
updateSized/repeats:5                             24.5 us         24.5 us        28335
updateSized/repeats:5                             24.5 us         24.5 us        28335
updateSized/repeats:5                             24.4 us         24.4 us        28335
updateSized/repeats:5_mean                        24.5 us         24.5 us            5
updateSized/repeats:5_median                      24.5 us         24.5 us            5
updateSized/repeats:5_stddev                     0.062 us        0.062 us            5
updateSized/repeats:5_cv                          0.25 %          0.25 %             5
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5                     14.7 us         14.7 us        47371
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5                     14.7 us         14.7 us        47371
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5                     14.7 us         14.7 us        47371
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5                     14.7 us         14.7 us        47371
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5                     14.7 us         14.7 us        47371
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5_mean                14.7 us         14.7 us            5
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5_median              14.7 us         14.7 us            5
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5_stddev             0.011 us        0.011 us            5
updateInSeriesSized/repeats:5_cv                  0.08 %          0.07 %             5
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5                      23.0 us         23.0 us        30493
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5                      23.0 us         23.0 us        30493
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5                      22.9 us         22.9 us        30493
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5                      23.0 us         23.0 us        30493
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5                      23.0 us         23.0 us        30493
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5_mean                 23.0 us         23.0 us            5
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5_median               23.0 us         23.0 us            5
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5_stddev              0.033 us        0.033 us            5
updateNoAliasSized/repeats:5_cv                   0.14 %          0.14 %             5
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5              13.8 us         13.8 us        50879
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5              13.8 us         13.8 us        50879
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5              13.8 us         13.8 us        50879
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5              13.8 us         13.8 us        50879
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5              13.7 us         13.7 us        50879
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5_mean         13.8 us         13.8 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5_median       13.8 us         13.8 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5_stddev      0.012 us        0.012 us            5
updateInSeriesNoAliasSized/repeats:5_cv           0.09 %          0.09 %             5
```

The benchmark actually report the opposite of my assumption: the Matrix-Matrix form is much slower then the sequence of Matrix-Vector multiplication.

Can someone explain this phenomena ?

Moreover, these computation are the bottleneck of my application. Does someone have some insight on how these operations can be made more efficient?

Here is my CMakeLists file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(cpp_sandbox LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)


add_executable(stack_alias stack_alias.cpp)
target_link_libraries(stack_alias
    PRIVATE
        Eigen3::Eigen
        benchmark::benchmark
)
```

Code is compiled in `Release` mode. I do not specify any optimization level to let Eigen optimize by itself (found it's the fastest approach).

Comment: Any question concerning the speed of C++ code must state the compiler and compiler settings used to build the application.  The most notable setting being the optimization level.  If you are running a "debug" or unoptimized build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with additional details.

Comment: With such small matrix there is nothing to parallelize.

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify your hardware when talking about performance issue

Comment: I think problem is that your `Stack` (terrible name comparing to functionality) was optimized by compiler more in one scenario. Benchmarks are hard to write properly since you are trying to trick optimizer. So in first glace looks like tests are invalid.

Comment: Could you specify how you "stack" things in more details ? Z would be 15x3 ? And what about D ? if a_stack, b_stack and c_stack are different sizes, you extend all of those to  the maximum size to form D ?

Comment: Did you try hard-coding the fixed dimensions?, e.g., `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> Z`, and `Eigen::VectorXd a_stack` (`VectorXd` is short for `Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>`).

Comment: @MarekR Thank you for the clarification.

How would you suggest to handle the benchmarks?

Comment: @ThibaultCimic I added some details in the question.
The vectors a_stack, b_stack and c_stack  will always be of the same dimension as they are generated using the same matrix M_stack

Comment: Here is assembly to read what could be optimized: https://godbolt.org/z/dKs1o81bb (to complex for me).

Comment: Here is CPPCON [showing what are obstacles to write correct google benchmarks](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk), this is old now google benchmark has function `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x)` which does `escape` shown in this demo.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the suggestion. I tried and edited the question with the new layout. Still, the result doesn't change...

Comment: Another thing you could try is `D.noalias() = M_stack.lazyProduct(Z)` -- probably Eigen chooses the generic Matrix-Matrix product. And if one size is small this causes more overhead than it benefits (only for larger products, there is a benefit of better cache usage). But I'm mostly speculating.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the suggestion !
I tried but I actually made it worse...

Comment: Another suggestion (also not tested): You could manually multiply `M` and `Z` blockwise, like so: https://godbolt.org/z/M1d7Yve61